# How load pdf file in new tab of the browser using dompdf plugin from cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, dompdf

I'm using cakephp 3 and a [this](https://github.com/DaoAndCo/cakephp-dompdf) dompdf plugin and need to show the pdf in a new tab of the browser and refresh the other page at the same time.
The method for this is run when the user send a form. So, I found a way for this adding target=_blank to the form but It is having problems with validators...when the form fails and return error messages, this page open a new tab...so...Can you help me with that?

Comment: So, when someone clicks a link, it should reload that page with one bit of output and also open a second tab showing the PDF? I don't think there is anything that you can do on the server side to implement this: the browser will load output into one tab. You may be able to get some of your desired functionality by including some JavaScript to open a new tab in your "success" output (but not in the validation errors output), but this might be less effective due to things like popup blockers.

Comment: thanks for answer, it's true.